# Heaviest Stone algorithm time complexity

Tags: javascript, array

I implemented the heaviest stone algorithm, but I am not sure about its time complexity. I'm doing sort which is O(nlogn), but it' inside a while loop.

Problem:

We have a collection of stones, each stone has a positive integer weight.

Each turn, we choose the two heaviest stones and smash them together.  Suppose the stones have weights x and y with x <= y.  The result of this smash is:

If x == y, both stones are totally destroyed;
If x != y, the stone of weight x is totally destroyed, and the stone of weight y has new weight y-x.
At the end, there is at most 1 stone left.  Return the weight of this stone (or 0 if there are no stones left.)

Example:

```
Input: [2,7,4,1,8,1]
Output: 1
Explanation: 
We combine 7 and 8 to get 1 so the array converts to [2,4,1,1,1] then,
we combine 2 and 4 to get 2 so the array converts to [2,1,1,1] then,
we combine 2 and 1 to get 1 so the array converts to [1,1,1] then,
we combine 1 and 1 to get 0 so the array converts to [1] then that's the value of last stone.
```

My solution:

```
var lastStoneWeight = function(stones) {
    if(!stones || stones.length === 0)  return 0;
    if(stones.length === 1) return stones[0];
    
    stones.sort((a,b) => b-a);
    
    while(stones.length > 1) {
        const x = stones[0];
        const y = stones[1];
        stones.splice(0, 2);
        if(x !== y) {
            stones.push(x-y);
            if(stones.length === 1) return stones[0];
            stones.sort((a,b) => b-a);
        } 
    }
    
    return stones.length > 0 ? stones[0] : 0;
};
```

By the way, is there a way to have a better performance? Maybe not sorting?

Thanks

Comment: If you're worried about efficiency, couldn't you simply go through the entire list and find the two heaviest stones instead of sorting everytime? You can create a new function for this, and I think it should give you a significant increase in performance.

Comment: For this case it approximates $$O(n^2\ln(n))$$ (as worst case in general) because you are sorting them in the while loop.

Comment: O(n^2 * log(n)) is yours. O(n^2) if you implement what @cliesens proposed. O(n * log(n)) if you are willing to implement heap.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is what I thought O(n^2log(n)). Could you please show me how could I change it to O(nlog(n)) or O(n) if it's possible.

Comment: A follow up problem is: "Each turn, we choose any two rocks and smash them together. At the end, there is at most 1 stone left.  Return the smallest possible weight of this stone (the weight is 0 if there are no stones left.)" Any idea how can I approach this problem in order to have the smallest possible weight

Comment: The data structure you want is a priority queue, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue, this essentially solves the problem of having to repeatedly sort the collection. Unfortunately js doesn't come with priority queues built in, the lack of good built in datastructures is an unfortunate fact about the language imo, so you'll have to implement it yourself or use a dependency.

Comment: Could you please show me an example of how a priority queue would solve this problem? I could using a Map() in javascript

Comment: I added a C++ solution here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/247668/smashing-two-heaviest-stones-until-at-most-one-stone-is-left-counting-number-o

It's a bit more complex and the crucial parts are implemented by the C++'s standard library, but I'm sure you can find code of the 3 functions on wiki. Map won't help you in any way here. For the followup problem, it looks like NP hard, because you can try all permutations of the input to find the smallest result.

Comment: But also it feels like smashing the two heaviest stones every time may already give the smallest possible result. So I would start by trying to logacily prove (or disprove) such statement.

Comment: If you dont mind i would like to hear back from you. Did it put you on the right path? After all I implemented the C++ solution just to show it to you...

Comment: And use @ and my name in further comments So i get a notification please :)

Comment: @slepic I'm looking for a solution in Javascript

Comment: I know but js does not have those heap functions. I meant it to show you how the stones problem can be solved using heap. But implementing the heap functions in js is up to you. Look them up on wiki, they are usualy called build-heap or heapify, sift-up and sift-down, or sometimes bubble-up and bubble-down.

Answer (score 8):

## Issue(s)

1. You sort descending, but then take and assign the heaviest stone to `x` and the second heaviest stone to `y` whereas in your problem you state "...stones have weights x and y with x <= y".
2. Code isn't as DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) as it *could* be.

## Suggestions

1. Provide `stones` a default/initial empty array value.
2. Sort descending and assign `const y = stones[0];` and `const x = stones[1];` and push new value `stones.push(y - x);` to match problem. (*Or normal sort ascending and take from array end, more on this later*)
3. Use array destructuring to assign to `x` and `y` since array::splice returns an array of spliced out values.
4. Sort once at the beginning of each iteration.
5. Remove extraneous array length checks, let the while-loop condition handle it.

### Code

```
const lastStoneWeight = (stones = []) => {
  if (!stones || !stones.length) return 0;

  while (stones.length > 1) {
    stones.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    const [x, y] = stones.splice(-2);
    if (x !== y) stones.push(y - x);
  }
  return stones[0] || 0;
};
```

If you can use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [Nullish Coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```
const lastStoneWeight = (stones = []) => {
  if (!stones?.length) return 0;

  while (stones.length > 1) {
    stones.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    const [x, y] = stones.splice(-2);
    if (x !== y) stones.push(y - x);
  }
  return stones[0] ?? 0;
};
```

Here I use the default sort (ascending) and splice off the last two elements, removes need to shift entire forward 2 indices.

### Using a Heap Data Structure

Since you ask about improved performance and the going suggestion is to use a heap/priority queue. This is a very similar implementation.

```
const lastStoneWeightHeap = (stones = []) => {
  if (!stones?.length) return 0;

  const heap = new PriorityQueue(); // <-- uses equivalent comparator as array::sort
  stones.forEach((stone) => heap.enq(stone)); // <-- populate heap

  while (heap.size() > 1) {
    const y = heap.deq();
    const x = heap.deq();
    if (x !== y) heap.enq(y - x);
  }
  return heap.size() ? heap.deq() : 0;
};
```

`t1` is regular algorithm
`t2` is version using heap/priority queue data structure

```
10 iterations x 10000 runs
    # Elements  t0 avg      t1 avg 
1   8           0.00363     0.00106 
2   16          0.01036     0.00157 
3   32          0.01781     0.00224 
4   64          0.09148     0.00432 
5   128         0.22560     0.00944 
6   256         0.56833     0.01618 
7   512         2.37584     0.06091 
8   1024        8.78741     0.12614 
9   2048        34.29092    0.29697 
10  4096        130.50169   0.63872
```

*Notes:*

- Time is in milliseconds

https://www.npmjs.com/package/priorityqueuejs

### Conclusion

Using a heap data structure is orders of magnitude an improvement. With the naive implementation it is clearly at least an \$O(n^2)\$ complexity as each time the dataset size doubles (2x) the runtime roughly quadruples (~4x) whereas the implementation using a heap roughly only doubles (~2x) the runtime with each doubling of the dataset.

## Performance Benchmarking

performanceBenchmark.js

```
const measurePerf = (fn, data, runs = 1e3) =>
  [...Array(runs).keys()]
    .map(() => {
      const start = performance.now();
      fn([...data]);
      const end = performance.now();
      return end - start;
    })
    .reduce((total, current) => total + current) / runs;

const toFixed = (val, fixed) =>
  Number.isFinite(val) ? Number(val).toFixed(fixed) : val;

export const benchmark = async ({
  functions = [],
  createRunData,
  iterations = 5,
  runs = 1e3,
  logIntermediateResults
}) => {
  logIntermediateResults && console.log(`${iterations} x ${runs}`);

  const results = [];

  logIntermediateResults &&
    console.log(
      `\t# Elements\t${functions.map((_, i) => `t${i} avg`).join("\t")}`
    );

  for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    const data = createRunData(i);

    const res = await Promise.all(
      functions.map((fn) => measurePerf(fn, data, runs))
    );

    results.push(res);

    logIntermediateResults &&
      console.log(
        `${i + 1}\t${data.length}\t${res
          .map((t) => `${toFixed(t, 5)}`)
          .join("\t")}`
      );
  }

  return results;
};
```

Setup & benchmark

```
const ITERATIONS = 10;
const RUNS = 1e4;
const SEED = 8;

const functions = [
  lastStoneWeight,
  lastStoneWeightHeap,
];

const createRunData = (i) => {
  const dataLength = SEED << i;
  const stones = [...Array(dataLength).keys()].map(() =>
    Math.floor(Math.random() * dataLength)
  );
  return stones;
};

benchmark({
  functions,
  createRunData,
  iterations: ITERATIONS,
  runs: RUNS,
  logIntermediateResults: true
});
```

Extended heap implementation benchmark

```
15 x 10000 
    # Elements  t0 avg 
1   8           0.00100 
2   16          0.00171 
3   32          0.00242 
4   64          0.00434 
5   128         0.00933 
6   256         0.01825 
7   512         0.05681 
8   1024        0.13715 
9   2048        0.27621 
10  4096        0.59631 
11  8192        1.24577 
12  16384       4.75092 
13  32768       6.09799 
14  65536       13.07677 
15  131072      28.88058
```

[image: Edit solitary-microservice-hbpxw]

Comment: The default [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) in JavaScript is *alphabetical*, even for numbers. It converts them to strings, so 10 would be before 2. You need to provide a sorting function.

Comment: @Kruga Thanks, I added a test case in the sandbox for an array with values like that and updated implementations.