# Smashing two heaviest stones until at most one stone is left - counting number of stone comparisions

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge

Based on this question:
[Heaviest Stone algorithm time complexity](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/247632/heaviest-stone-algorithm-time-complexity)

> Problem:
>
> We have a collection of stones, each stone has a positive integer weight.
>
> Each turn, we choose the two heaviest stones and smash them together. Suppose the stones have weights x and y with x <= y. The result of this smash is:
>
> If x == y, both stones are totally destroyed; If x != y, the stone of weight x is totally destroyed, and the stone of weight y has new weight y-x. At the end, there is at most 1 stone left. Return the weight of this stone (or 0 if there are no stones left.)

I implemented an `O(n * log(n))` solution using `std::*_heap` functions in C++.

Since those functions have an optional generic argument - the comparision function - I decided to implement my functions with that generic argument as well.

```
#include <algorithm>

template<class Iterator, class Compare>
typename Iterator::value_type stone_smash_destructive(Iterator first, Iterator last, Compare comp)
{
    std::make_heap(first, last, comp);
    while (first < last)
    {
        std::pop_heap(first, last--, comp);
        auto y = *last;
        if (first < last) {
            std::pop_heap(first, last--, comp);
            auto x = *last;
            if (comp(x, y)) {
                *last = y - x;
                std::push_heap(first, ++last, comp);
            }
        } else {
            return y;
        }
    }
    return {0};
}

#include <functional>

template<class Iterator>
typename Iterator::value_type stone_smash_destructive(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    return stone_smash_destructive(first, last, std::less<typename Iterator::value_type>());
}

#include <vector>

template<class Iterator>
std::vector<typename Iterator::value_type> make_vector(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    return {first, last};
}

template<class Iterator, class Compare>
typename Iterator::value_type stone_smash(Iterator first, Iterator last, Compare comp)
{
    auto v = make_vector(first, last);
    return stone_smash_destructive(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
}

template<class Iterator>
typename Iterator::value_type stone_smash(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    auto v = make_vector(first, last);
    return stone_smash_destructive(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

To take use of it I implemented a comparator that counts number of it's invocations.

```
#include <cstddef>

template<class BinaryCondition>
struct binary_condition_counter
{
    std::size_t & count;
    BinaryCondition condition;

public:
    using result_type = typename BinaryCondition::result_type;
    using first_argument_type = typename BinaryCondition::first_argument_type;
    using second_argument_type = typename BinaryCondition::second_argument_type;

    binary_condition_counter(std::size_t & count, BinaryCondition && condition): count(count), condition(condition) {}

    bool operator () (first_argument_type a, second_argument_type b) const
    {
        ++count;
        return condition(a, b);
    }
};

#include <utility>

template<class BinaryCondition>
binary_condition_counter<BinaryCondition> make_binary_condition_counter(std::size_t & count, BinaryCondition && condition)
{
    return {count, std::move(condition)};
}
```

The code of the tests may be a bit messy and they just spit out the numbers of comparisions to the `std::cout` but I am not much concerned about that.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

void test_stone_smash(std::size_t expected, std::vector<std::size_t> v)
{
    std::size_t count = 0;
    auto comp = make_binary_condition_counter(count, std::less<std::size_t>());
    assert(expected == stone_smash(v.begin(), v.end(), comp));
    assert(expected == stone_smash(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), comp));
    assert(expected == stone_smash_destructive(v.begin(), v.end(), comp));
    std::cout << "{";
    if (v.size())
    {
        auto limit = v.end() - 1;
        for (auto i = v.begin(); i < limit; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << *i << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << *limit;
    }
    std::cout << "}(" << v.size() << "): " << count / 3 << " comparisions.\n";
}

void test_stone_smashes_logarithmic(std::size_t exp, std::size_t base = 2)
{
    assert(exp < 23);
    std::size_t count;
    auto comp = make_binary_condition_counter(count, std::less<std::size_t>());
    std::size_t limit = ipow(base, exp) + 1;
    std::vector<std::size_t> v;
    v.reserve(limit);
    std::size_t mod = base;
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i <= limit; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(i);

        if (i % mod == 0 || (mod > base && (i - 1) % (mod / base) == 0))
        {
            count = 0;
            auto result = stone_smash(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
            std::cout << "[1, " << i << "] = " << result << ": " << count << " comparisions.\n";
            assert(((i - 1) % 4 < 2 ? 1 : 0) == result);

            if (i % mod == 0)
            {
                mod *= base;
            }
        }
    }
}

void test_stone_smashes_linear(std::size_t n, std::size_t step = 1, std::size_t start = 1)
{
    std::size_t count;
    auto comp = make_binary_condition_counter(count, std::less<std::size_t>());
    std::vector<std::size_t> v;
    v.reserve(n);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        auto val = start + i * step;
        v.push_back(val);

        count = 0;
        auto result = stone_smash(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
        std::cout << "[" << start << ", " << val << "](n=" << i + 1 << ",step="<< step << ") = " << result << ": " << count << " comparisions.\n";

        if (step == 1 && start == 1)
        {
            assert(((val - 1) % 4 < 2 ? 1 : 0) == result);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    test_stone_smash({0}, {});
    test_stone_smash({0}, {0});
    test_stone_smash({2}, {0, 1, 2, 5});
    test_stone_smash({1}, {1});
    test_stone_smash({0}, {5, 5});
    test_stone_smash({1}, {1, 2});
    test_stone_smash({1}, {2, 1});
    test_stone_smash({0}, {3, 1, 2});
    test_stone_smash({1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
    test_stone_smash({0}, {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21});
    test_stone_smash({4}, {1, 3, 8});

    test_stone_smashes_logarithmic(20);
    test_stone_smashes_linear(2000);
    test_stone_smashes_linear(100, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

I am more concerned about standard algorithm and templates usage.
For example, is there a standard alternative to my make_vector function with type deduction?

Also I know I should use some testing framework, but I am not concerned about that as well. Actually with asserts it should be just copy-paste from this post without need to install additional libs.

The `ipow(base, exponent)` (used in tests) is just an exponentiation `base^exponent`, I am not including it here.

The `#include`s are located above the code that uses them but I am not actualy showing the file system structure. Module separation is also no concern here.

But of course, feel free to comment on anything you want :)

The tests output:

```
{}(0): 0 comparisions.
{0}(1): 0 comparisions.
{2, 2, 3, 5}(4): 12 comparisions.
{1}(1): 0 comparisions.
{5, 5}(2): 2 comparisions.
{1, 2}(2): 2 comparisions.
{1, 2}(2): 2 comparisions.
{1, 1, 3}(3): 6 comparisions.
{1, 1, 1, 3, 5}(5): 19 comparisions.
{1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 8, 21}(8): 36 comparisions.
{4, 5, 8}(3): 6 comparisions.
[1, 2] = 1: 2 comparisions.
[1, 3] = 0: 6 comparisions.
[1, 4] = 0: 12 comparisions.
[1, 5] = 1: 19 comparisions.
[1, 8] = 0: 42 comparisions.
[1, 9] = 1: 47 comparisions.
[1, 16] = 0: 108 comparisions.
[1, 17] = 1: 115 comparisions.
[1, 32] = 0: 263 comparisions.
[1, 33] = 1: 270 comparisions.
[1, 64] = 0: 629 comparisions.
[1, 65] = 1: 638 comparisions.
[1, 128] = 0: 1450 comparisions.
[1, 129] = 1: 1465 comparisions.
[1, 256] = 0: 3296 comparisions.
[1, 257] = 1: 3303 comparisions.
[1, 512] = 0: 7350 comparisions.
[1, 513] = 1: 7365 comparisions.
[1, 1024] = 0: 16250 comparisions.
[1, 1025] = 1: 16278 comparisions.
[1, 2048] = 0: 35607 comparisions.
[1, 2049] = 1: 35571 comparisions.
[1, 4096] = 0: 77263 comparisions.
[1, 4097] = 1: 77261 comparisions.
[1, 8192] = 0: 166782 comparisions.
[1, 8193] = 1: 166815 comparisions.
[1, 16384] = 0: 358181 comparisions.
[1, 16385] = 1: 358585 comparisions.
[1, 32768] = 0: 766300 comparisions.
[1, 32769] = 1: 765531 comparisions.
[1, 65536] = 0: 1629347 comparisions.
[1, 65537] = 1: 1629708 comparisions.
[1, 131072] = 0: 3455996 comparisions.
[1, 131073] = 1: 3455976 comparisions.
[1, 262144] = 0: 7305131 comparisions.
[1, 262145] = 1: 7307617 comparisions.
[1, 524288] = 0: 15401610 comparisions.
[1, 524289] = 1: 15413884 comparisions.
[1, 1048576] = 0: 32400609 comparisions.
[1, 1048577] = 1: 32380097 comparisions.
...
```

To compile: `g++ -Wall -std=c++17 stone_smash_test.cpp -o stone_smash_test`

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
```